# what is this error pkg_resources distribution not found?

Tags: python, pkg-resources

I can import pkg_resources in shell but I don't know why do I get this error when I try to run pylint and some many there tools...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pylint", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2697, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 669, in require
    self.add(dist)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 572, in resolve

pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pylint==1.0.0
```

pkg_resources has seriously made my life miserable, I fixed it earlier with OSx 10.7 but i guess when i upgraded to 10.9 ..

Please before marking it as duplicate chat with me, there could be some other reason of the issue.. i will give you more info as you ask !!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error as well and I tried to upgrade my pip. It was causing an error for distribution because I had installed pip using easy_install. I used the below command in powershell windows and I didnt have a problem anymore.

```
easy_install --upgrade pip
```